# Unable to use mpl_toolkits to import Axes3D and axes3d to draw 3D plot using Python

Tags: python, plot

`I am getting this error again and again.

```
<ipython-input-8-6dc76a089dd9>:15: UserWarning: No data for colormapping provided via 'c'. Parameters 'cmap' will be ignored
  ax.scatter3D(X_new[mask, 0], X_new[mask, 1], X_new[mask, 2], c = 'b',
<ipython-input-8-6dc76a089dd9>:17: UserWarning: No data for colormapping provided via 'c'. Parameters 'cmap' will be ignored
  ax.scatter3D(X_new[~mask, 0], X_new[~mask, 1], X_new[~mask, 2], c = 'r',
Text(0.5, 0, 'feature1 ** 2')
<Figure size 640x480 with 0 Axes>
```

The code is given below:

```
import numpy as np
# Adding squared 2nd feature in the dataset
X_new = np.hstack([X, X[:, 1:] ** 2])
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D, axes3d
figure = plt.figure()
# Visualizing in 3D
ax = Axes3D(figure, elev = -152, azim = -26)
# print(ax)
# Plotting 1st all the points with y==0, & then all with y == 1
mask = y == 0
ax.scatter3D(X_new[mask, 0], X_new[mask, 1], X_new[mask, 2], c = 'b',
           cmap = mglearn.cm2, s = 60, edgecolor = 'k')
ax.scatter3D(X_new[~mask, 0], X_new[~mask, 1], X_new[~mask, 2], c = 'r',
           marker = '^', cmap = mglearn.cm2, s = 60, edgecolor = 'k')
ax.set_xlabel("feature 0")
ax.set_ylabel("feature 1")
ax.set_zlabel("feature1 ** 2")
```

It should have given a 3D figure, but it's showing error again and again.`

Comment: What is `X`? So that I can reproduce, because I am not familiar with the error.